# The Swift Make-It-Compile Challenge #4

Tags: programming-puzzle, swift

This is a challenge for the people using **Swift 2.0 beta 6**, it's not code golf, but it's a programming puzzle so I'm pretty sure this belongs here. The basic idea is: Make it compile. There are more details and a very nicely formatted playground [at the Github project](https://github.com/Kametrixom/The-Swift-Make-It-Compile-Challenge). Previous challenges are there as well, all set up to tinker. Solutions are included for the previous challenges, as they all have been solved.

### Rules

- You can't modify the given lines
- You can't insert anything between the given lines
- You can't provide custom functions for ones that are in the standard library, according to the syntax-hightlighed picture. This applies to the inverse as well.
- The given lines are not allowed to produce a warning (on default warning settings). However the code you append is allowed to produce warnings.
- The code may or may not crash at runtime, it only has to compile

### The Code

```
func doIt(inout s: D) {
    if case self = isUniquelyReferenced(&s),
        self.`self` = true where self {
        self.`self` = { [unowned x = [self, 7] as Self] n in
            print(x + n)
        } as () -> ()
    }
}
```

### The Picture

[image]

### Winner

The first one posting an answer that compiles and conforms to all the rules above wins and gets an entry in the projects Hall of Fame.

### EDIT: Hint

Upon submission of [Chris Goldsby](https://twitter.com/GoldsbyChris)'s 99% solution, he received the following hint:

> The syntax highlighting of

```
protocol P {
    typealias P
    var p : P { get }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just saying "latest swift beta version", could you specify which version that is, so that updates to swift don't break anything?

Comment: @isaacg Changed it, thanks :)

Comment: What's to stop me from commenting out all the lines?

Comment: @feersum The third rule, picture has to match

Comment: I believe this could be edited to fix it... but I don't know Swift, so I can't do it. Future reviewers , please try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this answer on behalf of [Chris Goldsby](https://twitter.com/GoldsbyChris) who managed to submit a

## 99% Solution ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/cgoldsby/b4f8a8ccf8550ffbd1a1)):

```
typealias D = NonObjectiveCBase

func ~=(left: Any, right: Bool) -> BooleanType {
    return true
}

func +(left: Any, right: Any) -> String {
    return ""
}

protocol &#128034;: class, BooleanType, ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    
    var `self` : () -> () { get set }
}

extension &#128034; {
    
    typealias Element = Any
    
    internal init(arrayLiteral elements: Any...) {
        self.init()
    }
    
    //
    
    func doIt(inout s: D) {
        if case self = isUniquelyReferenced(&s),
            self.`self` = true where self {
            self.`self` = { [unowned x = [self, 7] as Self] n in
                print(x + n)
            } as () -> ()
        }
    }
    
    //
    
}
```

Only the snytax highlighting of `D` doesn't match. That's remarkable as it is!

## 100% Solution

EDIT: Two days later he submitted [the following full solution](https://gist.github.com/cgoldsby/20fd0719a18954c8d58d), congrats!:

```
private func ~=(left: Any, right: Bool) -> BooleanType {
    return true
}

private func +(left: Any, right: Any) -> String {
    return ""
}

protocol Challenge4: class, BooleanType, ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    
    typealias D
    
    var `self` : () -> () { get set }
    
    func doIt(inout s: D)
}

private extension Challenge4 where D == NonObjectiveCBase {
    
    typealias Element = Any
    
    init(arrayLiteral elements: Any...) {
        self.init()
    }
    
    //
    
    func doIt(inout s: D) {
        if case self = isUniquelyReferenced(&s),
            self.`self` = true where self {
            self.`self` = { [unowned x = [self, 7] as Self] n in
                print(x + n)
            } as () -> ()
        }
    }
    
    //
    
}
```